# How to update the image of a specific button when it's clicked on?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tic-tac-toe

```
from tkinter import *

# Creating the main window
topper = Tk()
topper.geometry('414x417')
topper.resizable(False, False)
topper.configure(bg='green')

# Importing all images that'll be used
b7_img = PhotoImage(file="C:\\project images\\b7.png")
b8_img = PhotoImage(file="C:\\project images\\b8.png")
b9_img = PhotoImage(file="C:\\project images\\b9.png")
b4_img = PhotoImage(file="C:\\project images\\b4.png")
b5_img = PhotoImage(file="C:\\project images\\b5.png")
b6_img = PhotoImage(file="C:\\project images\\b6.png")
b1_img = PhotoImage(file="C:\\project images\\b1.png")
b2_img = PhotoImage(file="C:\\project images\\b2.png")
b3_img = PhotoImage(file="C:\\project images\\b3.png")
bX_img = PhotoImage(file="C:\\project images\\bX.png")
bO_img = PhotoImage(file="C:\\project images\\bO.png")

# This determines if it's player 1's or player 2's turn to give an input
player_turn = False

# This is the function that's supposed to replace/update the image of the designated button on-click
def btn_click(button):
    global player_turn
    if player_turn:
        button(image=bO_img)
        player_turn = True
    if not player_turn:
        button(image=bX_img)
        player_turn = False


b7 = Button(topper, height='114', width='115', image=b7_img, command=lambda: btn_click(b7)).place(x=0, y=0)
b8 = Button(topper, height='114', width='115', image=b8_img, command=lambda: btn_click(b8)).place(x=150, y=0)
b9 = Button(topper, height='114', width='115', image=b9_img, command=lambda: btn_click(b9)).place(x=300, y=0)
b4 = Button(topper, height='114', width='115', image=b4_img, command=lambda: btn_click(b4)).place(x=0, y=150)
b5 = Button(topper, height='114', width='115', image=b5_img, command=lambda: btn_click(b5)).place(x=150, y=150)
b6 = Button(topper, height='114', width='115', image=b6_img, command=lambda: btn_click(b6)).place(x=300, y=150)
b1 = Button(topper, height='114', width='115', image=b1_img, command=lambda: btn_click(b1)).place(x=0, y=300)
b2 = Button(topper, height='114', width='115', image=b2_img, command=lambda: btn_click(b2)).place(x=150, y=300)
b3 = Button(topper, height='114', width='115', image=b3_img, command=lambda: btn_click(b3)).place(x=300, y=300)


topper.mainloop()
```

Hi everyone, I am trying to create a simple tic-tac-toe game with Tkinter but I am facing an issue, I can't update the image of the designated button when the player clicks on it, I can't change the `image` keyword argument for the designated button using the `btn_click` function, whenever I try to it'll give `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

Is there any way I can solve the issue instead of having to create a specialized function for each button? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three issues in your code:

1. assigned result of `place()` (which always be `None`) to `bX` in line like `b7 = Button(...).place(...)`.  You need to separate the line into 2 statements:

```
b7 = Button(topper, height='114', width='115', image=b7_img, command=lambda: btn_click(b7))
b7.place(x=0, y=0)
b8 = Button(topper, height='114', width='115', image=b8_img, command=lambda: btn_click(b8))
b8.place(x=150, y=0)
b9 = Button(topper, height='114', width='115', image=b9_img, command=lambda: btn_click(b9))
b9.place(x=300, y=0)
b4 = Button(topper, height='114', width='115', image=b4_img, command=lambda: btn_click(b4))
b4.place(x=0, y=150)
b5 = Button(topper, height='114', width='115', image=b5_img, command=lambda: btn_click(b5))
b5.place(x=150, y=150)
b6 = Button(topper, height='114', width='115', image=b6_img, command=lambda: btn_click(b6))
b6.place(x=300, y=150)
b1 = Button(topper, height='114', width='115', image=b1_img, command=lambda: btn_click(b1))
b1.place(x=0, y=300)
b2 = Button(topper, height='114', width='115', image=b2_img, command=lambda: btn_click(b2))
b2.place(x=150, y=300)
b3 = Button(topper, height='114', width='115', image=b3_img, command=lambda: btn_click(b3))
b3.place(x=300, y=300)
```

2. You need to use `button.config(image=...)` to change `image` option instead of `button(image=...)` inside `btn_click()` function.
3. You assigned wrong value to `player_turn` (assign `True` when it is already `True`, `False` when it is already `False`).

Updated `btn_click()` function:

```
def btn_click(button):
    global player_turn
    if player_turn:
        button.config(image=bO_img)
    else:
        button.config(image=bX_img)
    player_turn = not player_turn
```

I think the button should be disabled after it is clicked so that it cannot be clicked again.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but is there a way I can disable the button without changing its color to gray?

Comment: You cannot change the disabled background, but you can reset the `command` option to `""` instead of disabling the button.